# Laravel 5 Create Database Connection with User Input

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm creating a CMS for a small project and need the user to be able to connect to a database during the initial setup.

I'm using a middleware to check whether the database connection is correct (and the tables exist) and if so to run the application. If not, to run the setup.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if(DB::connection()) {
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return redirect('/setup');
    }       
}
```

Essentially, the user will create a database themselves, then supply the database name, username and password during setup which will create a .env file with these details.

However, the application keeps failing with this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Is there a way to make this work?
Or is there a better way to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: I am also trying to make an installer page, would anyone can please tell me how I can do it ??

Answer (score 0):

From the mysql error you are not passing the mysql username and password to the query.
`Access denied for user 'you should have something here'@'localhost'`
`using password: NO` this should be `YES`
Since you are getting the mysql user and pass from the user running the setup script.